# fetch json local file get 404 not found

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have the structure of my project like this:

index.html
---folder js
---file  data.json
---file  index.js

In the data.json I have some data:

```
{
  "photographers":[
    {
        "name":"Mimi Keel",
        "id":243,
        "city":"London",
        "country":"UK",
        "tags":[
          "portrait",
          "events",
          "travel",
          "animals"
        ],
        "tagline":"Voir le beau dans le quotidien",
        "price":400,
        "portrait":"MimiKeel.jpg"
    }]
}
```

in index.js :

```
 fetch('./data.json',{
  headers : { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }})
   .then((response)=>{
  return response.json();
})
.then((data)=>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

I get the error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using just data.json or try multiple options. Also, leave your JSON file outside of the current file.

Comment: thank you for your help I moved my JSON file to the root of the project and I change the path and its work correctly

Comment: great!   happy for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the path to:
`fetch('./js/data.json',{...`

Comment: I tried this play with the path but still the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Since it's in the same directory, you don't actually need a fetch - you can just use an import statement

`import data from './data.json';`

or

`const data = require('./data.json');`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer that worked was written by **Allen Selasie**:

I was working with react and fetch, but got a 404 error even when the json file was in the same directory as the component fetching it.

Moving the json file to the same directory as the index.html that was using the component fixed the 404 error, and now I only need './(your_filename).json' as the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and guess what
Use this ideology:

1. Your directory is not from the js file but from the html page running the js file
2. Just write the directory as though the json file is being fetched from the html file running the script.‍‍